# Evalute cell array of anonymous functions with different arity

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, cell-array

I have a cell array of anonymous functions, all of which take different variables in general, e.g.

```
{@(x)x, @(x,y)x+y, @(y)y^2}
```

I want to evalute all of these functions for a pair of values `{x,y}`, i.e. do something like

```
{@(x)x, @(x,y)x+y, @(y)y^2}(x,y)
```

How can I do this in Matlab?

---

Edit: Since I could not find a nice solution, I manually parse the function definition now.

Comment: Figuring out the name of the input variable is far from trivial, as it requires introspection. I think this is possible to do in MATLAB, but it would require a lot of work, I think you'd have to manually parse the function definition, which you can retrieve as a string. In MATLAB, the actual names of input arguments are typically not shared outside the function definition.

Comment: The problem is not the arity, the problem is that functions with the same arity can use _different_ variables

Comment: Did you consider defining a single function `@(x,y) {x, x+y, y^2}`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo's suggestion is amazingly concise and clear.

Comment: @CrisLuengo The anonymous functions are the arguments of a function and are given by the user. Thus, I would have the change the interface of my function in order to use your solution, something which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd loop through the functions but I'd imagine there is a more elegant and concise way. I also used the `~` placeholder so no error will propagate for too many inputs. The `~` placeholder can be used for inputs and outputs that plan to be unused.

```
%Input variables%
x = 1;
y = 2;

Functions = {@(x,~) x, @(x,y) x+y, @(~,y) y^2};

%Looping through functions and evaluating%
for Function_Index = 1: length(Functions)
   
Functions{Function_Index}(x,y)

end
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**

Comment: Nice solution, converting the problem of identifying argument names into a simple argument order problem.